# Functions in python return variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Hey i need a help regarding the following code which i have found on edx practice session!

```
        def foo(x, y = 5):
           def bar(x):
             return x + 1
           return bar(y * 2)
      
        foo(3)
```

The first step is that the number 3 will go into the x variable in foo as the y has been already give 5. so foo(3,5). second step is def bar(3) which should return 4 right but why will this step go directly to return bar( y * 2) which is bar (5*2) and then return bar(10) and return 11.

Comment: Because that is just a function definition, not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

> second step is def bar(3)

That is not correct. `def bar(x):` is creating a second function with a **new** `x` variable. That inner `x` is shadowing the `x` in the outer scope, and does not share a value with the other `x`.

Once `foo` is entered, the definition of `bar` is evaluated (but the function is not run). Then control passes down to `bar(y * 2)`, and 10 is passed to `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems understanding what your code does, write it out more clearly. Your snippet is equivalent to:

```
def bar(x):
    ret = x + 1
    return ret

def foo(x, y=5):
    ret = bar(y * 2)
    return ret

foo(3)
```

As you can see, the '3' you pass to `foo()` is never used. `foo()` doubles y and adds one to it (via `bar()`)